# move set of files in unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have files like below

```
Activ_23676_03-10-2013.log.gz
Activ_23676_03-11-2013.log.gz
Activ_23676_03-12-2013.log.gz
Activ_23676_03-13-2013.log.gz
Activ_23676_03-14-2013.log.gz
Activ_23676_03-15-2013.log.gz
Activ_23676_03-16-2013.log.gz
Activ_23676_03-17-2013.log.gz
Activ_23676_03-18-2013.log.gz
Activ_23676_03-19-2013.log.gz
Activ_23676_03-20-2013.log.gz
Activ_23676_03-21-2013.log.gz
Activ_23676_03-22-2013.log.gz
```

Out of these files I want to move `Activ_23676_03-[10-16]*` only. How should I move them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply:

```
mv Activ_23676_03-1[0-6]* /path/to/new/location
```

Answer (score 2):

This should help you

`mv Activ_23676_03-1[0-6]* /destination`

`mv Activ_23676_03-[10-16]* /path/to/new/location`  will not work as it will move all files.

Comment: The original attempt won't move *all* files, just those whose first "day" digit is 1, a character in the range 0-1, or a 6.